# Insert one value into a table with all values from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

```
INSERT INTO inventory (film_id, store_id)
VALUES ((SELECT film_id FROM film WHERE title='EUCLIDEAN PI'), (SELECT store_id from store));
```

This doesn't work. The error returned is "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression".

Basically my inventory is supposed to have a copy of this specific film for every single store. If the id of ECULIDEAN PI is 347. The inventory table should show a copy of 347 for every single store_id in the store table.

```
film_id store_id  
347     1  
347     2  
347     3  
347     n
```

Where n is the last store_id. Store_id may not always be incremental.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention which specific database are you using, and the syntax changes a bit between them.

I'll assume it's for SQL Server. If that's the case, you can do:

```
insert into inventory (film_id, store_id)
select
  (select film_id from film where title = 'EUCLIDEAN PI'), 
  store_id
from store;
```

Result:

```
 film_id  store_id 
 -------- -------- 
 347      1        
 347      2        
 347      3        
 347      7        
 347      10
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b22fea8ad7701ad60ada9ad8141318d9).

Comment: I am using postgresql. Would this still work?

Comment: @INeedHelp101 Yes, I changed the dropdown to "PostgreSQL" in the fiddle, and it works as expected. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b22fea8ad7701ad60ada9ad8141318d9